# How to get unique key from android application dynamically that only my app knows about ?

Tags: android, encryption

I have gone through similar questions on stackoverflow and other sites but could not find satisfactory answer.So I am asking new question with detailed requirements.

We are building android application and need to communicate with application server.

There will be handshake between application server and android app to identify android application as valid source and then get one server generated unique device key or auth key.This auth key is stored on application.

Now to generate auth key from server idea is to take some predefined or mutually agreed string "Hello World" , encrypt it with some strong symmetric encryption algo using some key "key1".Then server will decrypt using same algo and same key.When server decrypts then if it gets "Hello World"  then it knows that source is infact only android app.

Now next steps is that server generates auth key and encrypts with same symmetric key algo and sends it to android app.Android application decrypts and stores locally.

Now I do not want to hard code symmetric algo key "Key1" on application side because anybody can decompile apk and know algo and key then write some automated batch to flood server with requests(ofcourse server side check will be there to check flooding,but I want to avoid on application  side).

I have read following solutions from web ;-

1. Use package name to identify uniqueness of application.
2. Generate key hash of signing certificate.

But all this information is known to public.My idea is to use same unique string as encryption key also.

If anybody has encountered similar problem , kindly guide.Or Am I thinking in wrong direction and this thing cannot be implemented on app side ?

Kindly share your experiences.

Answer (score 1):

You really can't.  Any key you use like this is going to be baked into the app.  It can all be trivially decompiled.  This is why it isn't cryptographically possible to identify an application.  All you can do is authenticate a user, such as through a password.  Because in that case an attacker can't get at the secret without attacking the user rather than just the application.

See https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/826/how-can-i-securely-authenticate-the-client-application-sending-me-data

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply. OK if i cannot keep this step secure then what are ways to delay revealing this step logic.so that it is difficult to brute force or flood at this step